# How to apply an image style to an image field within a node template

Tags: views, nodes, theming, media

I have a view where I can't use fields (the reason is complicated but I have to list the content as full content). I'm trying to figure out how to use differnt image styles from withing the node template. For instance, I have two image styles one that is 120 x 120 and one that is 360 x 360. I want to make the node template behave so that the first row displays the 360 x 360 and the subsequent rows display 120 x 120, but I can't figure out how to apply the image style to the field within the node template.

Comment: It sounds like something isn't quite right about your setup if you can't use the fields output, but anyway, I posted an answer that I hope is helpful. :)

Comment: well the issue is with the comments, I have some other pending question about grouping comments. (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18804/displaying-grouped-view-of-node-comments-in-a-view-listing-nodes) Essentially I'm trying to show a view of nodes and comments ...it seems the only way I can get the comments to display the way I want is to use the node format in views.

Answer (score 3):

I found this code somewhere as well and it seems to work within the template file.

```
 print theme('image_style', array( 'path' =>  $field_my_image[0]['uri'], 'style_name' => 'square_550'));
```

where the field_my_image is the name of your field  ....  I suppose it does the same as the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [image_style_url($style, $uri);](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/image_style_url/7)

```
foreach($node->imagefield[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $image) {
  echo '<img src = "' . image_style_url('style-name', $image['uri']) . '">';
}
```